# TCP, UDP, SCTP, RUDP or RAW?

Tags: networking, tcp, udp, protocols, rudp

I'm currently working on a networking library, but I don't know which way I should create it. The library should be designed to be used with games. Both reliable and unreliable packets are needed. Should I use "TCP and UDP", "UDP and SCTP", "UDP and create an RUDP protocol" or "RAW and build everything from ground up"? This is a long question that kept me struggling to much! I think creating a "robust" RUDP protocol is the best solution, but can I make a robust one?(extra work isn't a problem)

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each one of those is made for a reason. TCP for kinda slow reliable connections, UDP for fast unreliable connections, STCP is not commonly used so it's not certainly stable(not preferred), RUDP best used when both reliable and unreliable messages are needed and RAW is mostly used by organizations trying to build their own networking system.